# How to store values calculated in a template helper function and use them in another template function?

Tags: meteor

Consider this hypothetical example. Html:

```
{{#each items}}
    {{>item}}
{{/each}}
Price = {{itemTotals.totalPrice}}
Qty = {{itemTotals.totalQty}}
```

Js:

```
Template.cart.items = function () {
    var items = Items.find();
    var cartTotals = [];
    items.forEach(function(item){
        ..somecode...
        cartTotals.price += item.price;
        cartTotals.qty += 1;
    });
    return items;
}
```

And of course, we want a function "itemTotals". If we do price = {{items.itemTotals.totalPrice}}, and same for qty, we have to traverse items 3 times. I've tried to store the totals as a reactive variable as follows, but haven't been able to make it work:

```
Template.cart.rendered = function () {
    this.totals = new ReactiveVar([]);
}
Template.cart.items = function () {
    var items = Items.find();
    var cartTotals = [];
    items.forEach(function(item){
        ...
    });
    this.totals.set(cartTotals);
    return items;
}

Template.cart.totals = function () {
    return this.totals.get();
}
```

I'd like to 1) understand why the reactivity is not happening 2) find out if there is a way to have a template function wait on another - that would be more efficient than loading and reloading the values from a reactive variable

Comment: Try replacing `this.totals` with `Template.instance().totals` in the `items` and `totals` helpers. Also remember to `return items` in the `items` helper.

Comment: `Template.instance()` does not seem to make a difference. For the two get and set methods, you wind up with a "Cannot call method get/set of undefined" error. I'm confused as to why that is, since the rendered() method takes place before either of those calls are made - and putting a console.log in the methods confirms that. I should mention that using Session variables or deps has led to similar results, so I don't think I'm going about this the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other option suggested by Walter Zalazar would work, however, using Session forces us to store each value(price, quantity, etc) as a separate variable due to limitations of Session. After some trial and error, I've figured out the following way to store the entire totals array as one reactive variable:

```
totals = new ReactiveVar([]);

Template.cart.items = function () {
  //foreach loop as before, calculate cartTotals, etc
  totals.set(cartTotals);
  return items;
}

Template.cart.totals = function () {
  return totals.get();
}
```

and in html:

```
{{totals.totalPrice}}
{{totals.qty}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to try something like this

> Your .html

```
<template name="itemsList">
 {{#each items}}
    {{>item}}
 {{/each}}
 Price = {{totalPrice}}
 Qty = {{totalQty}}
</template>
```

> Your .js

```
Template.itemsList.helpers({
    totalPrice: function(){
       var price= 0;
       var items= Items.find({});
       items.forEach(function(item){
           price+=item.price;
       });
       return price;
    },
    totalQty: function(){
       return Items.find({}).count();
    },
    items:function(){
      return Items.find({});
    }
})
```

Just works!

Other option...

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Session.set("totalPrice");
  Session.set("totalQty");
})

Template.itemsList.helpers({
    totalPrice: function(){
      return Session.get("totalPrice");
    },
    totalQty: function(){
       return Session.get("totalQty");
    },
    items:function(){
      var price= 0;
      var items= Items.find({});
      var count= items.count();
      items.forEach(function(item){
           price+= Number(item.price);
      });
      Session.set("totalPrice",price);
      Session.set("totalQty",count);
      return items; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain, why do you think it is inefficient? Do you have some benchmark?

Comment: That would work, but in a real situation(the above is just a simple example), we're doing much more than return Items.find(). Picture additional logic where I wrote `...some code...`. Assume that traversing items and performing that logic is a costly operation, and the totalPrice is computed as a byproduct. Then the above would be inefficient, since we're traversing items a second time to get the totalPrice, even though another function has computed it.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment since you edited yours and I typed up a response to the edited version. Didn't see that you made another comment until now. But the above should answer your question. It's not inefficient in this case, but imagine every items.find is followed by a for loop with a lot of processing.